# Updating ProgressBar needs MessageBox

Tags: multithreading, progress-bar

I'm programming in c#(WPF).
I'm trying to make `MessageBox` which is enabled after a few `delays`. I'm trying to update a `ProgressBar` in a thread. Here is an `Action` which is used by named thread:

```
Action IncreaseProgressBarValue = () =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        window.progressBar.Value = i;
        window.indicator.Content = i.ToString();
        // MessageBox.Show("");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)jump);
    }
};
```

In normal run after a few second progressBar value is 100 without any update during seconds. If I remove comments in my code and show MessageBox during running time, my progressBar will be updated!

How can I update progessBar without any messageBox?

Comment: Classic threading problem. Only your UI thread can update the UI. Given that you have a sleep in the loop, your UI thread isn't updating the UI, instead its sleeping. You should replace the `Sleep` with a `await Task.Delay`

Comment: Please show me your code(idea). I don't now any thing about how to use `await`;

Comment: Questions like this are much easier to answer if you don't post such silly code.  There's no point to it, just set the progress bar to 100% and be done with it.  Show us the *real* problem you are trying to solve, there is always more than one way to solve such a problem and it doesn't necessarily require using a feature that you don't want to learn.